# Inno Setup creating an unwanted empty folder with value in DefaultDirName

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setup-project, pascalscript

Inno Setup installer is creating an unwanted empty folder using my initial value of `DefaultDirName`, even though I have set `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text = 'c:\preferredinstalldir'` in `CurStepChanged (curStep = ssInstall)`. The installer puts the files in the right installation folder, but because I have to assign a dummy value to `DefaultDirName`, it creates that dummy folder. I have tried using a `{code:xx}` function for the `DefaultDirName` but since the actually folder I want hasn't been determined until the wizard runs, I seem to need a placeholder folder (but I don't want it created!)

```
AppId = {code:GetAppId}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppCopyright={#MyAppCopyright}
VersionInfoCopyright={#MyAppCopyright}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL} AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}

DefaultDirName={code:GetFilesDestDir}  //this says error path not valid, no root/unc etc etc because the function has no path set yet 
DefaultDirName=c:\mydummyfolder //this creates a dummy folder even though   the files are installed correctly to location i set later in CurStepChanged (I assign WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := InstallPath )

DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName=SomeName
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup_setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
UsePreviousAppDir=no
UsePreviousLanguage=no
UninstallFilesDir = {code:GetFilesDestDir}\uninst

.............

function GetFilesDestDir(def:string): string;
begin
  if InstallPathSet then
  begin
    Result := InstallPath;
  end
end;
```

I've seen this question here
[Inno Script: Strange Empty Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049636/inno-script-strange-empty-folder)
but it wasn't answered and I couldn't post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution, setting CreateAppDir=no seems to do the trick.At least its no longer creating an empty folder at the initial dummy location.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot reproduce what you describe.

Changing `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text` in `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)` has no effect at all. It's too late.

---

Anyway, just change the value sooner. For example in the `InitializeWizard` or `CurPageChanged`.

Comment: Changing WizardForm.DirEdit.Text in currStepchanged ssInstall does have an effect, thats how i set the actual install folder based on some code choices.

Comment: From your comments and self-answer, I guess you do not install the files to `{app}`, but to `{code:GetFilesDestDir}`. Then it would behave as you describe. But you didn't tell us.